# Conservation of momentum in inelastic conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Why does momentum and velocity change along contact normal but not contact tangent in inelastic collisions?

Suppose a ball strike an inelastic surface. Its velocity component does not change along the tangent but changes along the normal. velocity component is e time along the normal while leaving. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The ball only feels an impulse along the normal direction and not the tangential direction. Hence there is only a change in momentum in the normal direction and not the tangential. It is probably worth noting that although the overall momentum is conserved when a ball strikes a very large wall the momentum of the ball does change (and so will that of the wall, but this will not be noticeable).

Comment: what if the ball motion has a tangential component to the surface and the surface has friction?

Comment: @brucesmitherson If the surface has friction then for a ball bouncing of it we can ignore it (in the idealised case). Let $F_f$ be the frictional force, then the impulse on the ball in the tangential direction is $F_f \Delta t$ where $\Delta t$ is the time the ball is in contact with the surface which is assumed to be very small (if not zero) and thus the impulse in the tangential direction basically vanishes.

Comment: why cant the same argument be made for the normal force?

Comment: @brucesmitherson The normal force is assumed to be very large (if not infinite) an as such the product $F_N \Delta t$ is finite and non-zero.

Comment: Agreed. But should not those implicit assumptions be in the answer so the OP can understand it?

Comment: @brucesmitherson probably, although they are in the comments now and it is my assumption that the OP is going to read them. (if you think otherwise, let me know and I will edit them in to my answer :)).

Comment: 1) Just let me clarify it was a suggestion, I am not trying to impose anything! 2) agreed, it is likely redundant to add the comments to the answer

Answer (score -1):

This happens because during the collision of a ball with the wall only a single point say A is in contact with the wall and the force gets applied along the line joining this point and the center.

Comment: Nowhere did it state the ball didn't deform.  I don't think  that's a very good reason.

Comment: @JMac The ball must deform (or the energy must be lost in some other way; sound? light? heat?) as the collusion is inelastic.

Comment: @YashasSamaga Exactly, and if the ball deforms that means there must be more than a single point of contact.

Comment: Nvm, sorry. I read "didn't" as "did"; haven't slept in a while :P